# Linking firebase to a new account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I have created an android app with my personal account on firebase and now I want to transfer this app to the required person.What I have seen that you can transfer the ownership by managing accounts in firebase console and transferring the ownership to required person through email.But the transferred project still have the earlier data like number of users who authenticated ,connectioins made(For example free number authentication allowed is 10000 so I have already utilised about more than 500 but I want them to have fresh start) and like I want to provide this app to multiple organisations and they all will have diff firebase accounts and none oragnisations will have common account.How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For a fresh start you need to change your package name and create an app with that package name for the person/organization in their own account. And while creating it will generate a new json file of google services, just replace your current json with new one.